# Create an icon library for React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I wanted to know if there is any guide to be able to create a dependency that is an icon library for react, I have a list of .svg and I want to create a library where you then upload it to NPM and installing in a project I can use the icons for examples as follows.

```
import { EyeIcon } from 'custom-icons'

export default function App() {
  return(
    <EyeIcon />
  )
}
```

Thank you